# how to censor the first 10 char in a string using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda, char

so I want to create a credit card encoder (if this even a word) that takes a string and put the first 10 digits of the string as `'*'`
this is the code I came up with:

```
public static string[] ToCencoredString(this string str)   
{
    char[] array = Enumerable.Repeat('*', str.Length-1).ToArray();
    array = array.Select((cha, index) =>
    {
        if (index < 10)
           array[index] = str[index];
    });
}
```

(ignoringe the fact the function returns `string[]` there is another part of the code which is not relevant)

I don't know why, but I keep getting `ArgumentNullException` which is odd because there is not a single value in `array` witch is `null`.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its probably just easier to `String.Substring` then add whats left to `new string('*');`

Comment: Why not simple concatenation with substring? `return "******" + str.Substring(10);`

Comment: @AleksAndreev  I need the code in this format because there are more overloads with missing parameters you take from the function caller as cencor string length

Comment: Why you return `string[]`?

Comment: I think you should change `str.Length-1` to `str.Length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use this more efficient version using [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_) and the [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_):

```
public static string ToCencoredString(this string str, int length = 10)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;
    string censored = new string('*', length);
    if (str.Length <= length) return censored;
    return censored + str.Substring(length);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What about changing it to something a bit more simple:

```cs
var result = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", 10)) + str.Substring(10);
```

Comment: what is string.Concat?

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Concat_System_String___

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the original array for iterating so that you can make use of its index to create the mask. A `String.Join()` may help you to produce the masked output. The code would be something like this:

```
string maskedInput = String.Join("", str.Select((c, index) => index < 10? '*' : c));
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ZiWSr) for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile. So I dont know how you managed to reach `ArgumentNullException`.

And that's not how you use LINQ. The correct way (although not a good way, since the answers above are apparently way better) to implement what's in your mind

```
array = array.Select((cha, index) =>
{
    if (index < 10)
        return array[index];
    else
        return str[index];
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I reached it during compile-time

Comment: and yes, I'm pretty new to LINQ

Answer (score 0):

$"{string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", 10))}{FIELD.Substring(10)}";